# How to add custom row level processing of a column in Django Model that is used by Viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my Model for eg. :

```
class Lics(models.Model):
    files_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    seqno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expire = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

the field 'expire' comes with a date. I have a function that does delta from 'now' when the api is called. How and where do I add an extra field in the  ViewSet when calling Lics.objects.all()  that has is added as a 4th field which shows 'days' = 4 for eg. if license is expiring 4 days from now.

Expected output :  `[{files_id:1, seqno:2, expire:'4-jan-2019', 'days':4 }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably add it as a `SerializerMethodField` so that it's calculated upon request.  In fact, this is very similar to [the example in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).  You want something like the following (NOTE: I have not tested this, it is just a slight modification of the documented example):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class LicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Lic

    def get_days(self, obj):
        cur_time = now()
        if cur_time > obj.expire:
            return 0
        return (obj.expire - cur_time).days
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad it helped.  When you get a chance, click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@RishiG has a good solution. As an alternative, you could also make a model property.

```
class Lics(models.Model):
    files_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    seqno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expire = models.TextField(blank=True)

    @property
    def days(self):
        // calculation code goes here
```

Then, you just include "days" in the "fields" argument of your serializer.

```
class LicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Lic
    fields = ('files_id', 'seqno', 'expire', 'days')
```

I generally decide on my approach based on WHERE I want to be able to access this data. For example, if I might want to operate directly on the `days` property of a model instance I put it in the model. If I only care about bubbling this data up in a view, I put it in the serializer.